# Создание объекта в параметрах метода

Tags: java, объекты

Никак не могу разобраться в чем отличие. Вот исходный код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First GUI");
    JButton button = new JButton("hi");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds( 200, 200, 800, 400);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(new JButton("go!"), BorderLayout.WEST);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

`new` в строчке `frame.add(new JButton("go!"), BorderLayout.WEST);` создаёт новый объект класса `JButton`, но только без ссылки? Или это что-то другое значит?
И в чем будет отличие, если заранее объявить кнопку `JButton button = new JButton("hi");` и непосредственно в параметре для `add` использовать `button`?

Comment: А что вы считаете ссылкой? Новый объект `JButton` был создан и передан в метод `add` первым параметром. Что конкретно подразумевается под "передан" можно прочитать, например, в ответах к [этому вопросу на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/3432401). Отличие - во втором случае у вас будет переменная `button` - соответственно, вы сможете воздействовать на объект напрямую. На то что будет передано в метод это никак не повлияет.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрался, то есть получается, что отличие этих двух записей в том, что в первом случае у меня ссылка на новый объект JButton не создаётся?

Comment: Переменная не создается. Если бы не было ссылки, телу метода было бы нечего использовать.

Comment: Объект в обоих случаях создаётся, и программа про него знать будет, но во втором случае у вас ссылка на объект будет, а в первом - нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все стало ясно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы объявляете:

```
JButton goButton = new JButton("go!");
```

вместо прямой передачи нового объекта:

```
frame.add(new JButton("go!"), BorderLayout.WEST);
```

У вас имеется 2 преимущества:

1. Изменение свойств кнопки по переменной, даже после её добавления

   `frame.add(goButton, BorderLayout.WEST);`

   `goButton.setText("GO GO GO!");`
2. Документирование кодом, т.е. создав переменную и дав ей логичное имя, другой программист, который будет читать ваш код, скорее всего быстрее поймёт, вашу задумку, не прибегая к помощи комментариев и/или документации.

Однако в некоторых случаях допустимо создавать объект без создания переменной, когда это само собой очевидно, это уменьшит размер кода.

Comment: потому что документация кода обычно требуется для других программистов, ну или для себя будущего, а в момент написания кода, самому программисту это мало поможет, если он конечно разбирается в написанном им же коде.

Comment: А, понял вас, да, возможно предложение построил некорректно.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что возможность изменения переданного объекта такое уж преимущество...